# Unsure if choice of slopes and random effects makes sense in linear regression

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to find out if Burst_Energy is influenced by StopType (consonant type), afterburst duration, and Burst_duration.

My model in R is so far (including interactions):

lmer(Burst_Energy ~ StopType * Burst_duration * Afterburst + (Burst_duration * Afterburst | Speaker) + (1 | StopType).

My question is essentially if this makes sense at all. My justification is as follows:

I nested Burst_duration and Afterburst within speaker, as I suspect that speakers will vary on this due to individual variation.

All speakers say the same consonants, so that isn't the problem - instead I have some doubts about the (1|StopType). I believe this is supposed to state that there is random variation in the baseline of StopType (which makes sense given that there are 4 different consonant types that vary in different ways). But I do not know if this is the correct way to do that.

Does this make sense? What might be a better way to improve this?